# Creating prepared geometries with OGR from Python

Tags: python, ogr

Is it possible to create a prepared geometry object using the Python SWIG `geos.ogr` module? It seems that Shapely and GeoDjango both have this functionality, but I can't see any mention of it in the standard Python module source or documentation. Unless I'm missing something, this seems somewhat of an oversight.

http://toblerity.github.io/shapely/manual.html#prepared-geometry-operations
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geos/#prepared-geometries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"There's currently no access to GEOS prepared geometries in OGR. They are just 
internally used by OGR since GDAL 1.10 to evaluate the layer spatial filter."

http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2013-April/036101.html